# How to use ${...} in Camel K Kafka URL?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I have saved topic in header and try to access it in the Kafka URL as below:

```
from(...)
.process(...)
.to("kafka:${header.topic}?brokers=localhost:9092")
```

Unfortunately it says the Kafka URL is invalid：

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [${header.topic}]
```

I have tried replace the `to(...)` with `.log("${header.topic}")` and the expected value can be printed in the logline.

Does anyone know what causes the issue, am I supposed to escape the dollar sign or the curly braces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use send dynamic so replace to with toD

Comment: Thanks Luca, it works!

Answer (score 2):

The header body and property values are dynamic values and can take a different value each time the stream triggers. You have to specify this to the camel and toD method do this.

Comment: Thanks eray_p1, it helps!